# GameCenter: endTurnWithNextParticipants not advancing

Tags: ios, game-center, ios8.1

In the sandbox environment, I'm having trouble advancing a turnbased match to the next player.

Initial conditions:

- Player A and Player B on Device A and Device B, respectively.
- Both logged into the sandbox
- Both players can see each other's GC status message
- Player A creates a match and invites player B
- Player A ends the turn

In my "end turn" function I do the following:

```
    NSLog(@"size = %ld", updatedMatchData.length);

    //move the current player to the bottom of the list
    NSMutableArray *nextPlayers = (NSMutableArray *)theMatch.participants;
    NSLog(@"%@", [nextPlayers description]);

    GKTurnBasedParticipant *firstGuy = nextPlayers[0];
    [nextPlayers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [nextPlayers addObject:firstGuy];

    NSLog(@"------");
    NSLog(@"%@", [nextPlayers description]);

    //send the match to the servers
    //"theMatch" was recorded in turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatch

    [theMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:nextPlayers
                              turnTimeout:GKTurnTimeoutDefault
                                matchData:updatedMatchData
                        completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"WTF?");
        }
    }];
```

That produces the following log output:

```
size = 26926
(
"<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x174018630 - playerID:G:1084583147 (local player) status:Active matchOutcome:None lastTurnDate:(null) timeoutDate:(null)>",
"<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x174018ba0 - playerID:G:12962188 status:Invited matchOutcome:None lastTurnDate:(null) timeoutDate:(null)>"
)
------
(
"<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x174018ba0 - playerID:G:12962188 status:Invited matchOutcome:None lastTurnDate:(null) timeoutDate:(null)>",
"<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x174018630 - playerID:G:1084583147 (local player) status:Active matchOutcome:None lastTurnDate:(null) timeoutDate:(null)>"
)
```

However, player B does not receive an invite or a turn. Player B's game center app shows no active games or turns. Player A's game center continues to show that he *still* has a turn pending. Each time I restart and re-execute the test, Player A racks up yet another pending turn.

Player A fires player:receivedTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive right after I end the turn, but didBecomeActive is set to NO.

So then I changed the timeout to 30 seconds. 30 seconds after playerA ends the turn, playerA fires didBecomeActive (no). PlayerB finally receives an invite prompt. Player B fires didBecomeActive, with a value of YES.

Why does my turn not advance immediately to player B after player A ends the turn? Why does player A seem to have another turn (which then times out and passes over to player B)?

Comment: Please if you could help me : The log output two times as shown by you. Is it the log result on two different devices by you?

Comment: It's logging the array contents before and after I modify the array.

Comment: In my case this array prints : 
[
<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x60000000c430 - playerID:G:25153527799 (local player) status:Active matchOutcome:None lastTurnDate:(null) timeoutDate:(null)>,
<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x60000000cd50 - playerID:(null) status:Matching matchOutcome:None lastTurnDate:(null) timeoutDate:(null)>
]
What should I do with this It's not finding the 2nd player for me.

Comment: You need to open a new question, show your code and explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sure, then how could I let you know by the time I have opened the question?
I've seen a lot of help provided by you here to a number of different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this. Do not attempt to edit the match object. Don't directly edit the matchData, or any other component of the match. Create a copy, do whatever you need to do to the copy and resubmit the copy.

My attempt to sort the players produced all sorts of erratic results until I created a completely separate participants array and sorted that. Then it worked as advertised.