# iOS - issue with rematchWithCompletionHandler in Sandbox

Tags: ios, game-center

I have the following code:

```
   if(tappedItem.match.status == GKTurnBasedMatchStatusEnded){
        [[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] findMatchWithViewController:self delegate:self debug:false  invite:tappedItem.player];
        return;
        NSLog(@"Participants %@", [tappedItem.match.participants description]);

        [tappedItem.match rematchWithCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
             }

             else
             {
                 [[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] setMatch:tappedItem.match];
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                  postNotificationName:ShowGameScreen
                  object:tappedItem.match];
             }

         }];
    }
```

I've got a number of people Beta testing it via TestFlight with sandbox enabled, but for some reason I get the following error when trying to rematch:

> {GKServerStatusCode=5121, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed because the player is invalid., NSUnderlyingError=0x17045cdd0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. status = 5121, **Invitation from: 224002977 to: 225851510 is not allowed because they are neither friends nor have recently played**"}

The match was ended properly, so it's not that:

```
[_match
        endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:data
        scores:scores
        achievements:nil
        completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {}];
```

I'm thinking this is an isolated issue with Sandbox, but unless I can test it I'm not confident that it will work in the once released.

### Edit #2:

Here's the tappedItem.match object:

```
    <GKTurnBasedMatch 0x174250200 -
matchID:0049f124-b8c3-43d8-9964-beaf58af69f8
bundleID:--- REMOVED ---
status:GKTurnBasedMatchStatusEnded
message:''
creationDate:2015-06-24 23:12:31 +0000
currentParticipant:(null)
participants:<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x174205450 -
playerID:G:225851510
status:Done
matchOutcome:Won
lastTurnDate:2015-06-24 23:12:32 +0000
timeoutDate:(null)>,
<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x174205460 -
playerID:G:224002977 (local player)
status:Done
matchOutcome:Lost
lastTurnDate:2015-06-24 23:16:56 +0000
timeoutDate:(null)>
matchData.length:295
matchDataMaximumSize:65536
exchanges:(null)>
```

So as you can see, the match was only finished a few hours ago. This works as expected as long as they are friends, but I need to test the rematch functionality before I can put it live.

### Edit #1:

I get the same error code when I use findMatchForRequest:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    if(player != NULL)
        request.recipients= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:player];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;
```

According to the error, "they are neither friends nor have recently played", yet they have played recently.

Comment: what do you get when you NSLog the participants?

Comment: the participants of the _match is as expected, which is how it knows to invite 225851510 for example.

Comment: <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x174202860 - playerID:G:179544789 status:Done matchOutcome:Won lastTurnDate:2015-06-23 03:03:09 +0000 timeoutDate:(null)>

Even if I do a standard invite using request.recipients= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:player]; it has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am grasping at straws here, but your edit looks similar to a problem I wrestled with trying to build the array of nextParticipants at the end of a GKTurnBasedMatchTurn [GameCenter: endTurnWithNextParticipants not advancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522794/gamecenter-endturnwithnextparticipants-not-advancing). It didn't give me a coherent error, it just kept sending the turn back to the same player. The root seemed to be: Game Center does not like it when you pass it pointers to non-mutable objects that it previously sent to you.

I had to change

```
NSMutableArray *nextPlayers = (NSMutableArray *)theMatch.participants;
..some sorting logic deleted for brevity...
[theMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:nextPlayers
                          turnTimeout:GKTurnTimeoutDefault
                            matchData:updatedMatchData
                    completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
{
```

To:

```
NSMutableArray *nextParticipants = [NSMutableArray new];
for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *participant in theMatch.participants)
{
    ...some sorting logic deleted for brevity...
    [nextParticipants addObject:participant];
}

[theMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:nextParticipants
                          turnTimeout:GKTurnTimeoutDefault
                            matchData:updatedMatchData
                    completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
{
```

Your code blocks don't show where you're getting **player** from, so it's not clear to me if these are new or re-used objects. I'm wondering if this code

```
if(tappedItem.match.status == GKTurnBasedMatchStatusEnded){
    [[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] findMatchWithViewController:self delegate:self debug:false  invite:tappedItem.player];
```

and this code

```
if(player != NULL)
    request.recipients= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:player];
```

are the problem. What happens if you try creating copies of the player and pass that to the rematch and findMatch calls?

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure that's the problem I'm facing but I'll have a look and see if that helps. Edit - Nope. It all works fine if they are friends. The problem is when they're not friends, according to the error I haven't played a game with the person I'm rematching. I'm almost convinced this might be a Sandbox issue unless someone else can shed some more light.